# How to add Chosen placeholder text on mobile devices?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, jquery-chosen

I'm trying to fix a bug on a Worpress theme using jquery-Chosen multi select tool. Here is the page in which the form is: http://mitramimoveis.com.br/temp/ . The placeholder works well on desktops and is input through the theme's interface:
[Theme's interface](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SvpXM.png)

However, on mobile devices, the multi select fields only show "0 selected", on Android and "0 Items", on iPhone. The placeholder I put doesn't show up at all. I already tried adding a blank Option as first, using custom jQuery through the "Custom CSS and JS" Wordpress plugin, but it didn't work - all the answers I found regarding this issue, addressed this as a solution.
The html code for the forms:

```html
<!-- Row -->
<div class="row with-forms">
    <div class="search-form-_property_type col-md-3 custom-tipo-imovel">
        <select multiple name="_property_type[]" name="_property_type" id="_property_type" data-placeholder="Tipo de imóvel" class="chosen-select">
            <option value="">Tipo de imóvel</option>
            <option value="apartamento">Apartamento</option>
            <option value="casa">Casa</option>
            <option value="sobrado">Sobrado</option>
        </select>
    </div>
    <div class="search-form-_cidade col-md-3 custom-tipo-imovel">
        <select multiple name="_cidade[]" name="_cidade" id="_cidade" data-placeholder="Cidade" class="chosen-select">
            <option value="">Cidade</option>
            <option value="Curitiba">Curitiba</option>
            <option value="Campo Largo">Campo Largo</option>
        </select>
    </div>
    <div class="search-form-tax-region col-md-3 custom-tipo-imovel">
        <select multiple name="tax-region[]" data-placeholder="Bairro" class="chosen-select">
            <option value="">Bairro</option>
            <option value="bigorrilho">Bigorrilho</option>
            <option value="cabral">Cabral</option>
            <option value="centro">Centro</option>
            <option value="portao">Portão</option>
        </select>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-3 ">
        <button class="button fullwidth">Buscar</button>
    </div>
</div>
```

How can I solve this? I need the users to know what are the options about on each field and the theme doesn't offer a label (which I also don't want to use). Thanks.

*I noted that the first option is the same as the placeholder and has an empty value.

Answer (score 0):

Hope this is welcomed feedback but placeholder text isn't ADA compliant. Here are some resources that can help you take a different approach if you so choose:

https://www.w3.org/WAI/GL/low-vision-a11y-tf/wiki/Placeholder_Research

Example:
https://material-ui.com/components/selects/